# Multiple search criteria using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I have to write a code for searching the database for a particular set of values based on multiple user inputs. At the max the user can input 5 search criteria and may be not even 1 or 2 or 3.

How should I proceed on this? Can prepared statement help me out?

I am using MS Access as the database.

Answer (score 0):

a straightforward solution is you build your where sub clause and maintain the paraList by userinput.

e.g. you have 5 criteria a,b,c,d,e.

in your program, check if there is an input in A, if yes, add it to where (could be Like or =), then add the input value to a List(paraList).

at the end, you concatenate the built where subclause with your preparedStatement, and set the parameter with paraList.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this using `NamedParameterStatement`

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE (:P_FIELD1 IS NULL OR FIELD1 = :P_FIELD1)
AND (:P_FIELD2 IS NULL OR FIELD2 LIKE :P_FIELD2)
```

I recommend you to use a required field to limit scan (something like data range)

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE DATE_FIELD BETWEEN :P_DATE1 AND :P_DATE2)
AND (:P_FIELD1 IS NULL OR FIELD1 = :P_FIELD1)
AND (:P_FIELD2 IS NULL OR FIELD2 LIKE :P_FIELD2)
```

Hope it helps